# Compile time calculations in C

Tags: microcontroller, c

I have been implementing a control software in C programming language. One of 
the software modules represents a communication table for some proprietary 
communication protocol. Each record in this table has one item (among others) 
consisting of 8 bits. This item represents properties associated to this record. 
Each record can has below given properties:

*reported,
event_logged,
time_logged,
archived,
global*

I need to define the communication table and for sake of readibility I don't
want to fill the properties of each record with values 0-31. My idea was to
at first define below given bit masks for individual bits in the properties
byte:

```
#define REPORTED       0x10
#define EVENT_LOGGED   0x08
#define TIME_LOGGED    0x04
#define ARCHIVED       0x02
#define GLOBAL         0x01
```

Then I wanted to define a macro with parameters which will prepare the content
of the properties based on human readable values

```
#define Create_properties(reported, event_logged, time_logged, archived, global){ \
  (uint8_t)reported | (uint8_t)event_logged | (uint8_t)time_logged |              \
  (uint8_t)global                                                                 \
}
```

The planned usage is following. For example one of the records in the communication
table will be event logged and time logged so I will write the macro in this manner

```
Create_properties(0, EVENT_LOGGED, TIME_LOGGED, 0, 0, 0)
```

and the expected result is 01100. I have been facing a problem that I am not
able to compile this source code. I always receive compiler error 
"braces around scalar initializer". I have been using the gcc compiler. Does 
anybody know why does this error occur? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: In general, I would advise to ask pure programming questions like this on https://stackoverflow.com/. Your question is on-topic here & just fine, but you'll get far better quality if you ask this to C gurus at SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is pure programming, and best suited to a different exchange.

Comment: @Lundin Your comment proves that at least one of those C gurus have a presence at "our" site as well. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curly braces `{}` are not used for macro definitions. Try removing them and see if it works:

```
#define Create_properties(reported, event_logged, time_logged, archived, global) \
  (uint8_t)reported | (uint8_t)event_logged | (uint8_t)time_logged |              \
  (uint8_t)global
```

Comment: It works without curly brackets. Thank you, Justin.

Comment: @Steve Then be sure to select the answer (the check button) so that future searches will reveal an answered question.

Comment: This is a dangerously-written macro. As a bare minimum, you need to surround it with parenthesis. The casts are superfluous and can be removed, or you can cast the end result to the intended type.

Answer (score 5):

Since these are only 8 bit numbers, you could safely use an enum. Pick some code prefix that makes sense - I don't know what your code is supposed to do so I used `STUFF_` as place-holder, to be replaced by a better name.

```
enum
{
  STUFF_REPORTED     = 0x10,
  STUFF_EVENT_LOGGED = 0x08,
  STUFF_TIME_LOGGED  = 0x04,
  STUFF_ARCHIVED     = 0x02,
  STUFF_GLOBAL       = 0x01,
};
```

Then simply create a macro for each case:

```
#define STUFF_EVENT_TIME_LOGGED ( (uint8_t)(STUFF_EVENT_LOGGED | STUFF_TIME_LOGGED) )
```

Making a function-like macro such as `Create_properties` gives no benefit, since it might be confused for a function and will have zero type-safety, making it hard to read and dangerous both. So I wouldn't recommended it, function-like macros should be avoided if possible. But of course it can be done too:

```
#define Create_properties(reported, event_logged, time_logged, archived, global) \
  (uint8_t) ((reported) | (event_logged) | (time_logged) | (archived) | (global))
```

Notably, your casts to `uint8_t` were completely pointless, because each operand of `|` will get integer promoted to `int` anyway. If you should cast to something before the `|` takes place, it would need to be `uint32_`. Or you can just cast to `uint8_t` after the operation, as in my macro above.
See [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules) to learn more.